# Вопрос по реализации key-value хранилища в python

Tags: python, json, map

Пробую написать key value хранилище.
В словаре хранятся значения ключ : лист значений

Проблема:
Не добавляются значения в словарь в лист с одинаковыми ключами, хотя условие вроде реализовано верно. В чем может быть проблема, подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
import tempfile
import argparse
import json
storage_path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'storage_1.data')

db = {}

# Преобразуем словарь в json
def to_json(dict_name):
    return json.dumps(dict_name, ensure_ascii=False)

def write_to_file(dict_name):
    with open(storage_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(to_json(dict_name))
        
def read_to_file():
    with open(storage_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
       data = json.load(f)
    return data   
    

#Задаем аргументы командной строки
parser = argparse. ArgumentParser(description = 'My parser')
parser.add_argument('--key',
                    type = int,
                    default = None,
                    help = 'key of data (default: None)'
                    )
parser.add_argument('--val',
                    type = int,
                    default = None,
                    help = 'value of data (default: None)'
                    )
args = parser.parse_args()

# Логика хранилища
if args.key != None and args.val != None:
    
    db = read_to_file()
    if args.key in db:
        db[args.key] = db[args.key] + [args.val]
        write_to_file(db)
        
    elif args.key not in db:
        db.update({args.key: [args.val]})
        write_to_file(db)
        
if args.key != None and args.val == None:
    db = read_to_file()
    print(db[f'args.key'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Я проверил, правда без командной строки, руками задал аргументы - всё работает, добавляется. Но есть пара замечаний.

1. Функция `to_json` не нужна, `json` умеет писать сразу в файл, точно также как он умеет читать из файла

```
def write_to_file(dict_name):
    with open(storage_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        json.dump(dict_name, f, ensure_ascii=False)
```

2. В последней строке кода вы забыли фигурные скобки поставить в `f-строке`, должно быть так:

```
print(db[f'{args.key}'])
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я смотрю ты тоже особо не внимательный)

Comment: @chernyahovsky2010 Я не понял вашу мысль, разверните её, пожалуйста )

Answer (score 0):

Возможно это костыль, но я делаю список из значения и затем использую `append()`:

```
if key in data:
    if type(data[key]) is not list:
         data[key] = list(data[key])
    data[key].append(value)
    write_data(data)
```